# How do I generate text matching a regular expression from a regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, random, data-generation

Yup, you read that right. I needs something that is capable of *generating* random text from a regular expression. So the text should be random, but be matched by the regular expression. It seems it doesn't exist, but I could be wrong.

Just a an example: that library would be capable of taking '`[ab]*c`' as input, and generate samples such as:

> abc 
>   abbbc 
>   bac

etc.

Update: I created something myself: Xeger. Check out http://code.google.com/p/xeger/.

Comment: Cool idea - interested to hear the results.

Comment: This would indeed be quite useful!

Comment: I think any "...or more" selectors would have to be limited though or you could end up with 1,000,000 character words :S

Comment: I don' think such a library exists. You could look into the perl String::Random module which implements something similar for a restricted subset of patterns

Comment: You know the saying about the monkeys that could write Shakespeare (Infinite Monkey Theorem) ... well quick and dirty solution: generate random string until you have one that match. That could take a while :-). I would like to see a real reply though.

Comment: This sounds like it might be an interesting little project.

Comment: Same question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274011/random-text-generator-based-on-regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274011/random-text-generator-based-on-regex) I haven't tried it. Good question!

Comment: Trying to see if I can use Ruby Randexp running using JRuby, and get some support for it in Java that way.

Comment: Keep in mind that Java 7 will be able to execute Ruby natively.

Comment: I just created Xeger, a library that allows you to generate text from regular expressions. It's hosted here: http://code.google.com/p/xeger/

Comment: Your lib is really, really *cool* ! Thanks !

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just created a library for doing this a minute ago. It's hosted here: http://code.google.com/p/xeger/. Carefully read the instructions before using it. (Especially the one referring to downloading another required library.) ;-)

This is the way you use it:

```
String regex = "[ab]{4,6}c";
Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
String result = generator.generate();
assert result.matches(regex);
```

Answer (score 7):

I am not aware of such a library. If you're interested in writing one yourself, then these are probably the steps you'll need to take:

1. Write a parser for regular expressions (you may want to start out with a restricted class of regexes).
2. Use the result to construct an [NFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_state_machine).
3. (Optional) Convert the NFA to a [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).
4. Randomly traverse the resulting automaton from the start state to any accepting state, while storing the characters outputted by every transition.

The result is a word which is accepted by the original regex. For more, see e.g. [*Converting a Regular Expression into a Deterministic Finite Automaton*](http://lambda.uta.edu/cse5317/spring01/notes/node9.html).

Comment: I have been looking for a library that would create an NFA from regex in Java. I know the above would work, since I used to do that in Javascript ages ago.

Comment: I guess this would be worth to take a look at: http://www.brics.dk/~amoeller/automaton/

Comment: I implemented Xeger based on the library I mention above.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833197.aspx) [a few](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/source.html) [implementations](http://fractal.csie.org/~vincent/) of such a beast, but none of them in Java (and all but the closed-source Microsoft one very limited in their regexp feature support).

Answer (score 2):

based on Wilfred Springer's solution together with 
http://www.brics.dk/~amoeller/automaton/ i build another generator.
It do not use recursion. It take as input the patter/regularExpression minimum String length and maximum String length. The result is an accepted String between min and max length. It also allow some of the XML "short hand character classes".
I use this for an XML Sample Generator that build valid String for facets.

```
public static final String generate(final String pattern, final int minLength, final int maxLength) {
    final String regex = pattern
            .replace("\\d", "[0-9]")        // Used d=Digit
            .replace("\\w", "[A-Za-z0-9_]") // Used d=Word
            .replace("\\s", "[ \t\r\n]");   // Used s="White"Space
    final Automaton automaton = new RegExp(regex).toAutomaton();
    final Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
    final List<String> validLength = new LinkedList<>();
    int len = 0;
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    State state = automaton.getInitialState();
    Transition[] transitions;
    while(len <= maxLength && (transitions = state.getSortedTransitionArray(true)).length != 0) {
        final int option = random.nextInt(transitions.length);
        if (state.isAccept() && len >= minLength && len <= maxLength) validLength.add(builder.toString());
        final Transition t = transitions[option]; // random transition
        builder.append((char) (t.getMin()+random.nextInt(t.getMax()-t.getMin()+1))); len ++;
        state = t.getDest();
    }
    if(validLength.size() == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(automaton.toString()+" , "+minLength+" , "+maxLength);
    return validLength.get(random.nextInt(validLength.size()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python implementation of a module like that: http://www.mail-archive.com/python-list@python.org/msg125198.html It should be portable to Java.