# Libraries or tools for generating random but realistic text

Tags: text, random, markov-chains

I'm looking for tools for generating random but realistic text.  I've implemented a Markov Chain text generator myself and while the results were promising, my attempts at improving them haven't yielded any great successes.

I'd be happy with tools that consume a corpus or that operate based on a context-sensitive or context-free grammar.  I'd like the tool to be suitable for inclusion into another project.
Most of my recent work has been in Java so a tool in that language is preferred, but I'd be OK with C#, C, C++, or even JavaScript.

This is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578789/library-to-generate-text-from-a-regular-expression-in-java), but larger in scope.

Comment: In reference to your comment below - what are your parameters for similarity to the original text? Word length? Character probability? Sentence length? In characters or words? Perhaps if you get more specific in your requirements, something can be found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extending your own Markov chain generator is probably your best bet, if you want "random" text. Generating something that has context is an open research problem.

Try (if you haven't):

- Tokenising punctuation separately, or include punctuation in your chain if you're not already. This includes paragraph marks.
- If you're using a 2- or 3- history Markov chain, try resetting to using a 1-history one when you encounter full stops or newlines.

---

Alternatively, you could use [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu) in two passes with your corpus:

1. Analyse sentences to determine common sequences of *word types*, ie nouns, verbs, adjectives, and adverbs. WordNet includes these. Everything else (pronouns, conjunctions, whatever) is excluded, but you could essentially pass those straight through.
   This would turn "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" into "The [adjective] [adjective] [noun] [verb(s)] over the [adjective] [noun]"
2. Reproduce sentences by randomly choosing a template sentence and replacing [adjective], [nouns] and [verbs] with actual adjectives nouns and verbs.

There are quite a few problems with this approach too: for example, you need context from the surrounding words to know which homonym to choose. Looking up "quick" in wordnet yields the stuff about being fast, but also the bit of your fingernail.

---

I know this doesn't solve your requirement for a library or a tool, but might give you some ideas.

Comment: i discovered wordnet recently while seraching for a solution similar to this one

Answer (score 0):

I've used for this purpose many data sets, including wikinews articles.

I've extracted text from them using this tool:
http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/~mr04069/WikiExtractor.py