# Regular Expression to generate a string

Tags: regex

I am using a tool to generate test data for our database. For columns that are string fields, we have the option of entering a regular expression that will be used to generate values for the column. I would like a regular expression that generates a 15 character string as follows:

1. Characters 1-6 should consist of the YYMMDD (current year,month,day) such as "100702". If it's not possible for RegEx to determine the current date, a hard-wired value of "100702" would be fine.
2. Characters 7-8 should be either '25' or '26'
3. Characters 9-15 should a sequential series of digits starting with '0000001', then '0000002' etc. If this cannot be done, a random, but unique, set of 7 digits would work.

Is this possible?

Comment: you might want to mention what "flavor" of regex you're looking for, as they can vary (for instance, C# versus Javascript)

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get the current date, a incrementing number or a random set of digits out of a regular expression.

Comment: Nothing here can be done with a regex, besides the `2[56]` part. However, you can trivially write a function that does that. For the last part, you can use a running ID (for example, on Oracle there's a Sequence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, regex does not *generate* text, it *matches* text.

However, if you're using Java, take a look at [Xeger](http://code.google.com/p/xeger/) which can do what you want.

Also, see these similar questions:
[Using Regex to generate Strings rather than match them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them)
[How do I generate text matching a regular expression from a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578789/library-to-generate-text-from-a-regular-expression-in-java)
[Reverse regular expressions to generate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905229/reverse-regular-expressions-to-generate-data)