# is there any way to get all the possible outcomes of a regular expression pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

is there any way to get all the possible outcomes of a regular expression pattern?. everything I've seen refers to a pattern that is evaluated against a string. but what I need is to have a pattern like this:

```
^EM1650S(B{1,2}|L{1,2})?$
```

generate all possible matches:

```
EM1650S
EM1650SB
EM1650SBB
EM1650SL
EM1650SLL
```

Comment: You don't see this very often because the vast majority of regex patterns tend to have an infinite number of possible outcomes.

Comment: Not infinite. Just humongous.

Comment: @Alfabravo - Many (most?) RegExs I've seen have a `*` in them somewhere and if not "0 or more", usually a "1 or more" token. Those tokens typically give you an infinite list, since "or more" == "infinite".

Comment: Sounds very hard, most regexps can match an infinite number of strings

Comment: Here's another thread on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614962/create-set-of-all-possible-matches-for-a-given-regex

Comment: By the way, if the Regex is not surrounded by `^$` you don't even need `*` or `+` to make it have an infinite number of matches

Comment: @JuanMendes - The `^` and `$` tokens just indicate, essentially, another specific character. _not_ having those doesn't indicate an infinite set of matches at all. You _still_ need a "X or more"-type token to get an infinite match.

Comment: @cdeszaq; That's not correct. for the pattern `/ab/`, the following strings match it. Xab, XXab, XXXab, XXXab... See what I mean? http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/zaae4/

Comment: @JuanMendes - Depending on what you mean by match, yes you are  correct. I interpreted "match" to mean "give  me the text that matches", not "does this text match". With my interpretation, the result would be "ab" in all cases, therefor, not  infinite.

Comment: well, the token ^ always mark the begin of pattern and $ idem the end, so there be a finite numbers of combinations as result

Comment: Please consider migrating to cstheory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random string based on a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959850/generate-a-random-string-based-on-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, no. In this case, you have almost no solution space.

There's a [section covering this in Higher Order Perl (PDF)](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/pdf/06InfiniteStreams.pdf) and a [Perl module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Regexp%3a%3aGenex). I never re-implemented it in anything else, but I had a similar problem and this solution was adequate for similarly-limited needs.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools that can display all possible matches of a regex.

Here is one written in Haskell: https://github.com/audreyt/regex-genex
and here is a Perl module: [http://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Genex](http://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp%3a%3aGenex)

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything for JavaScript

Comment: Interesting. Regexp-Genex limits `*` to `{0,3}` and `+` to `{1,4}`, ostensibly to make it more pretty, but that has the side effect of removing the infinite solution space that most regexes have.

Comment: Cool, the genex assume that `*` is `{0,3}` and `+` is `{1,4}` and therefore produces a finite number of permutations. Wow this is my second comment that I'm late to and ends up being a copy of someone else's comment.

Comment: Yes, it's not perfect. Here's a discussion thread on Reddit about this topic: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/hya57/from_a_regex_generate_all_possible_strings_it_can/

Comment: yes, thanks, i will review, in fact i need a tool in javascript, asp, asp.net (c# or vb) or php

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, yes. The regex generates a finite number of valid string, so they can be counted up.

You'll just have to parse the regex. Some part of that (`EM1650S`) is mandatory, so think for the rest. Parse by the `|` (or) symbol. Then enumerate the strings for both sides of it. Then you can get all possible combinations of them.

Some regex (containing `*` or `+` symbols) can represent an infinite number of strings, so they cannot be counted.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for some indication of _how to get the result_, not _only_ if it can be done...

Comment: This is an indication on how to get it done, it's not easy, I don't expect anybody to take their time to write the code for the OP

Comment: Yes, though simulating a DFA may not be that hard for these simple regexes.

Comment: It would probably be easier to generate the list by hand than to write the code to parse the regexp and generate output.

Comment: @JuanMendes - My comment is prior to an edit. Initial answer was just the 1st paragraph.

Comment: yes Kevin B, it's easy, but the idea is automatixe this process

Answer (score 1):

From a computational theoretic standpoint, regular expressions are equivalent to finite state machines. This is part of "automata theory." You could create a finite state machine that is equivalent to a regular expression and then use graph traversal algorithms to traverse all paths of the FSM. In the general case a countably infinite number of strings may match a regular expression, so your program may never terminate depending on the input regular expression.