# Converting a regular expression to a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there a way of generating a string that would match a regular expression in Ruby

e.g.

```
regex           output
^\d{6}$         875914
^\d{3}-\w{2}    584-AS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a [response on a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274011/random-text-generator-based-on-regex) - Matt Aimonetti's [randexp](http://github.com/mattetti/randexp#readme) might be of some use.  Not generalised to all regexp though...

EDIT: [This version](http://github.com/benburkert/randexp) looks more up-to-date.

Comment: Yes, that looks more promising than what I posted.

Comment: This gem looks sweet, going to look further into this.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but this looks like something you're looking for: http://code.google.com/p/xeger/

Note that I cannot believe it will handle more complex regex-es (using look-arounds, back-references, etc.). But again, I haven't tested it.

EDIT: sorry, I now just saw you're looking for a Ruby implementation...

Comment: That is... interesting. Poorly documented though, and the 2 tests they have there don't reveal much...