# Get example matches that fit a regular expression

Tags: regex, testcase

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Random Text generator based on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274011/random-text-generator-based-on-regex)
>   [Using Regex to generate Strings rather than match them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them)

Hi,
I need a matches generator for my regular expressions.
E.g. for input like:

```
[A-Z]+[0-9]?
```

I get output:

```
FDLJUIOAF
LFDSJKHI8
B
IJKL5
```

And so on. I need this to show client what commands are currently supported so he can tell me what he wants to be added.

Does anyone know if there are such services?

Comment: Ah, cool - you want to run a regexp engine IN REVERSE!  Do you want to  generate all possible cases (not always possible), or just all cases up to a particular length, or just N random cases which work?

Comment: There are some similar questions here: * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205411/random-string-that-matches-a-regexp * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274011/random-text-generator-based-on-regex

Answer (score 0):

Problem is - for some expressions you can have an unlimited number of strings that match it. You could brute-force all strings of length 5, but that is very computationally intensive already. I am of the opinion that a human can do a better REPRESENTATIVE job.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a microsoft tool which does exactly this job:

msdn.microsoft.com : [The regular expression generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833197(VS.80).aspx)

Note that the dialect may be different from the one you are using - check carefully.

Comment: This seems to be awfully complex to set up. Not really a nice, small tool, apparently.