# How to convert regular expression to all possible cases?

Tags: javascript, node.js

convert a regular expression to all possible cases

For Example:

1.9856[1-4] then it should return values like 98561,98562,98563,98564

2.98[4-5]65 then it should return values 98465,98565

Comment: Hello @bharatsaikumar, welcome to stackoverflow, As you provided input and output, kindly provide your attempt to fix this issue

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274011/random-text-generator-based-on-regex

Comment: will it always have a single range?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `/\[(\d)-(\d)\]/` and [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get the `start` and `end` of the range. Then use a `for` loop to [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the match with numbers from `start` to `end`

```js
function getCombinations(str) {
  const regex = /\[(\d)-(\d)\]/,
        [match, start, end] = str.match(regex),
        output = []

  for (let i = +start; i <= +end; i++)
    output.push(str.replace(match, i))
  
  return output
}

console.log(getCombinations('1.9856[1-4]'))
console.log(getCombinations('2.98[4-5]65'))
```

This works for only single range in the input string. For multiple ranges, you can use [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to get multiple matches and `replace` based on the `index` of the match

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to match exact numbers or you can use `\d` to match any digits.

For your first example where 9856[1-4] then it should return values like 98561,98562,98563,98564, 
you can return all numbers in a string that begin with `9856` and ends with any number ranging from `1-4` like so:

`let nums = "985612, 985622, 985633, 985644, 985655"`

`let regex = /9856[1-4]/g`

`let result = nums.match(regex)`

`console.log(result)`

For the second example where 98[4-5]65 then it should return values 98465, 98565

`let nums = "98465, 98565"`

`let regex = /98[4-5]{2}65/g`

`let result = nums.match(regex)`

`console.log(result)`