# How can you print all the characters that satisfy a regular expression?

Tags: regex, unicode

Is there a way of printing out every character that satifies a given regular expression?

For example, can I print all characters that matches regular expression, let's say, in Javascript:

```
[A-Za-z_-]|[\u00C0-\u00D6]|[\u00D8-\u00F6]|[\u00F8-\u02FF]|[\u0370-\u037D]|[\u037F-\u1FFF]|[\u200C-\u200D]|[\u2070-\u218F]|[\u2C00-\u2FEF]|[\u3001-\uD7FF]|[\uF900-\uFDCF]|[\uFDF0-\uFFFD]|[\u10000-\uEFFFF]
```

Example taken from [Turtle specification](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/turtle/).

EDIT: JavaScript implementation of the solution proposed by Toby and Peter Boughton.

```
var out = "",
  str = "";
for (var i = 32; i < 983040; i++) {
  str = String.fromCharCode(i);
  if (str.match(/[A-Za-z_-]|[\u00C0-\u00D6]|[\u00D8-\u00F6]|[\u00F8-\u02FF]|[\u0370-\u037D]|[\u037F-\u1FFF]|[\u200C-\u200D]|[\u2070-\u218F]|[\u2C00-\u2FEF]|[\u3001-\uD7FF]|[\uF900-\uFDCF]|[\uFDF0-\uFFFD]|[\u10000-\uEFFFF]/)) {
    out += str;
  }
}
console.log(out);
```

Comment: This has been asked several times before on SO - only able to supply one link in the duplicate field, but here's a few more:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905229/reverse-regular-expressions-to-generate-data
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205411/random-string-that-matches-a-regexp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748253/how-to-generate-random-strings-that-match-a-given-regexp
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015449/regex-like-syntax-or-cfg-for-generating-cartesian-product-of-concatenated-string

Comment: You're right that the core of these questions is similar, but in the links you've provided the problem is to generate a random string that matches the given regular expression. I just want to get every possible *character* that matches the expression.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't see that it was a one-character regex. Kinda odd that, but Toby's suggestion will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to do what you ask would be to loop through all possible characters one-by-one and "collect" each one that's a match into a buffer of some sort.

Comment: Well, but then there's the question how can you generate all possible characters?

Comment: Something like `for (i=32;i<983040;i++){ if (chr(i).matches(regex){ output(chr(i)) } }` - that's not working code, but should give you the idea. Implementing it not as a regex would be faster.