# Reverse regular expressions to generate data

Tags: regex, algorithm

In one of the StackOverflow Podcasts (the one where guys were discussing data generation for testing DBs -- either [#11](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/podcast-11/) or [#12](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/podcast-12/)), Jeff mentioned something like "reverse regular expressions", which are used exactly for that purpose: given a regex, produce a string which will eventually match said regex.

What is the correct term for this whole concept? Is this a well-known concept?

Comment: More on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205411/random-string-that-matches-a-regexp

Comment: http://www.texamples.com/how-to-generate-random-passwords-in-java/ this might help you.

Answer (score 6):

The Perl module `String::Random` (in the CPAN) does this.  Takes a subset of regular expressions, and does a random walk through it.

Comment: Will String::Random necessarily generate all possible values in the solution set? I have a similar problem but I need all possible values. I'm willing to heavily restrict my language.

Answer (score 5):

Abstract: [Recursive transition network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_transition_network) (with the [postmodernism generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodernism_Generator) as an interesting example)

One specialization would be your "reverse regex".

---

As to the terminology: A *regular expression* is a form of *grammar* that describes all the *words* belonging to a specific *regular language* (namely all the inputs *matched* by the expression).

Therefore one could call your question: *"How can create a random word that matches a given regex"* or *"How can I obtain a random word belonging to a specified regular language"*.

Comment: A context free grammar (CFG) is not regular, as can be proved using the pumping lemma. However, the idea of an RTN can still be applied, using a nondeterministic finite-state automaton (NFA) instead.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, but a regular one is context free, so the same concept can be applied (being nothing but a specialization).

Answer (score 0):

It absolutely possible to generate data from regular expressions. Some open source projects are under development in this area.

A tutorial about [how to generate random password from regex](http://www.texamples.com/how-to-generate-random-passwords-in-java/) will explain you how it is done. [xeger](http://code.google.com/p/xeger/) (reverse of regex, an opensource project) is used in the tutorial. Please got through the tutorial to learn more.