# JavaScript/jQuery How to show regEx for user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have regEx of each input and I'd like to show user example of correct input value.

regEx:

```
^\+[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{10,19}
```

show for user:

```
+0.1234567890
```

May be anybody know plugin for my task?

Comment: You have `RegExp` object in `JavaScript`. Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Just manually give some examples.

Comment: ..( And if I want to automatically?

Comment: it is most likely that a tool that could do that would not produce an expected result. should it create `+000.0000000000`  or should it be `+013.0123456789` or `+900.9999999999000000000` and that is just about your simple regular expression. so in such a case it is easier to create a sample yourself. create pairs of `regex => sample` in a list so that you can easy validate your samples.

Comment: This is an interesting idea which I did not understand at first about what you are asking for. This requires some development of custom algorithms I suppose. Its already discussed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110101/auto-generated-examples-for-regexp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905229/reverse-regular-expressions-to-generate-data, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205411/random-string-that-matches-a-regexp

Comment: Do you want only numbers ? If so, you may try a function to genenate a random number between 2 values and concatonate to your needs ...

Comment: @63ek So are you just after random output like this: http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/ns9-iwb (refresh page for different outcomes)

Answer (score 0):

Use "source" property of the RegExp object. This property contains the text of the RegExp

```
var regexp = /^\+[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{10,19}/;
document.write("The RegExp is: "+regexp.source);
```

It displays => The RegExp is : ^+[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{10,19}

Source: [JavaScript RegExp source Property](http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_source.asp)