# Is it possible to generate an example string based on a regex pattern?

Tags: c#, regex, string

In my application the user can enter his own regex pattern into a text box so he can force a certain input for another user/text box. Is it possible for the user to see an example of a string that would match the regex he has entered? For example if he was to enter: `^[A-Z]{2}$`, it would generate a string like "`XX`" to show the user he can only enter two capital letters.

If there's no easy way to accomplish this (and I assume there isn't), how difficult would it be to build? Or does something like this already exist?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205411/random-string-that-matches-a-regexp, it may help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [Xeger](http://code.google.com/p/xeger/). It looks like it can do what you want. It's in Java though.

Here is an example from the test suite:

```
   @Test
    public void shouldGenerateTextCorrectly() {
        String regex = "[ab]{4,6}c";
        Xeger generator = new Xeger(regex);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String text = generator.generate();
            assertTrue(text.matches(regex));
        }
    }
```

**Update**: thanks to  Nikos Baxevanis, the dk.brics.automaton have been ported to **C#** at https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for.. but for C#. At least I have something I can use as reference.

Comment: Xeger is just a thin wrapper around http://www.brics.dk/~amoeller/automaton/ which is DFA/NFA implementation of some regexp operations. Maybe there is something like that available for C# somewhere?

Comment: @MartinWickman Yes, both the dk.brics.automaton and the xeger sources have been ported to C# at https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare

Answer (score 8):

For C# you may also want to look at project [Fare](https://github.com/moodmosaic/Fare). For more details have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841454/convert-nfa-to-dfa/8240209#8240209) answer.

**Example**

```
var regex = @"((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\://){1}\S+)";
var xeger = new Xeger(regex);

var result = Regex.IsMatch(xeger.Generate(), regex);
// -> Prints 'true'
```

Comment: Nikos, it would be very useful if you show a code sample using Fare

Comment: Alberto, I just added an example. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I once needed such thing too, so I created a simple program with gui using xeger lib mentioned above. Simply run .jar from dist folder (jre is required)
https://github.com/ogyct/SampleFromRegex