# PHP component that generares random string from regex

Tags: php, regex

I am searching for PHP component that generates random string from regex. I've searched through this forum, but found only PERL etc. solutions ([Random string that matches a regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205411/random-string-that-matches-a-regexp)). Is there such an open source class?

Comment: regexes are for matching strings that have already been generated, not generating them.

Comment: Generally questions asking for libraries etc. are off topic for SO; you might reword your question referencing the PERL solutions you found and how to convert to PHP.

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn: In other words I want to generate random string that will match a selected regex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random string that matches a regexp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205411/random-string-that-matches-a-regexp)

Comment: If you know the rules of the regex, in php you would probably just create a list of allowable characters and build your random string by selecting random characters from that list.

Comment: @Basti M ... Ok, so what is the PHP equivalent for String::Random mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205411/random-string-that-matches-a-regexp?lq=1 ?

Comment: look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15969145/1807643), it mentions a php lib

Comment: @Basti M: Oh I was so blind, thank you very much

Comment: @r3mus google `php random string regex`, third link :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A library called *ReverseRegex* can be found [here](https://github.com/icomefromthenet/ReverseRegex).
As of January 2014 the project seems not to be dead.

Usage seems to be as simple as

```
$lexer = new  Lexer('[a-z]{10}');
$gen   = new SimpleRandom(10007);
$result = '';

$parser = new Parser($lexer,new Scope(),new Scope());
$parser->parse()->getResult()->generate($result,$gen);

echo $result;
```

Give it a regex, give it a random seed and generate your string.
The above example, taken from the github-site, generates a ten character long random string consisting only of letters.

(originally found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15969145/1807643))

Answer (score 4):

<s>I'm not familiar</s> I wasn't (until now) familiar with any php libraries that can do this, and converting something like [xeger](https://code.google.com/p/xeger/) would be a *tremendous* undertaking.

Instead, you could simply do something like this:

```
function random($length)
{
    $random_string = "";
    $valid_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{}\\|";

    $num_valid_chars = strlen($valid_chars);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $random_pick = mt_rand(1, $num_valid_chars);
        $random_char = $valid_chars[$random_pick-1];
        $random_string .= $random_char;
    }
    return $random_string;
}

echo random(20); //generates a random string, 20 characters long.
```

Comment: Simplified this answer: `$validCharacters = range(0, 9); //select your char using range()` Then `$randVal = implode('', array_rand ( $validCharacters , $length ));`