# Generate alphanumeric string with 2 letters and 5 digits

Tags: php, random

I'm generating a unique 5 digit code using the following.

```
$randomUniqueNumber = rand(10000,99999);
```

I need to change this to an alphanumeric number with 5 digits and 2 letters.

The below gives me an alphanumeric number, but not restricted to just 2 letters.

```
$generated = substr(md5(rand()),0,5);
```

How would I generate a random string with 5 digits, and two letters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP component that generares random string from regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030978/php-component-that-generares-random-string-from-regex) `[0-9]{5}[a-z]{2}` would work

Comment: Is this for creating a password? If yes, have it look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837432/how-to-generate-random-password-with-php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to do it, but the following is verbose to get you going.

```
<?php
// define your set
$nums = range(0, 9);
$alphas = range('a', 'z');

// shuffle sets
shuffle($nums);
shuffle($alphas);

// pick out only what you need
$nums = array_slice($nums, 0, 5);
$alphas = array_slice($alphas, 0, 2);

// merge them together
$set = array_merge($nums, $alphas);

// shuffle
shuffle($set);

// create your result
echo implode($set); //86m709g
```

https://3v4l.org/CV7fS

Edit:

After reading *I'm generating a unique 5 digit code using the following.* I suggest, instead, create your string by changing the base from an incremented value, rather than random (or shuffled) as you will undoubtedly get duplicates, and to achieve no dupes you would need to pre-generate and store your entire set of *codes* and pick from them.

Instead look at something like [hashids](https://hashids.org).

Answer (score 0):

Try combining random generation of digits and letters. Here's a PHP example:

```
<?php
// Generate 3 random digits
$digits = rand(100, 999);
// Generate 2 random letters
$letters = chr(rand(65, 90)) . chr(rand(65, 90)); // ASCII range for uppercase letters
// Combine digits and letters
$randomUniqueCode = $digits . $letters;
echo $randomUniqueCode;
?>
```

This code will generate a 5-character alphanumeric string with 3 digits and 2 letters.