# Using RNGCryptoServiceProvider to "simulate" throwing a dice

Tags: c#, cryptography

I've been trying to simulate rolling a 6-faces dice in C#. I thought using RNGCSP was better than Random because it is more secure.

I tried using [MSDN's example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve this, but there are a few things that I didn't understand from the code:

1. How do you generate 5 digit long numbers with RNGCSP?
2. How do you generate numbers from 1 to 6 (excluding zeroes)?

Comment: How much security do you need to simulate a dice roll?

Comment: I need it to be completely random.

Comment: "How do you generate numbers from 1 to 6 (excluding zeroes)?" The example simply uses the [mod operator %](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396): `return (byte)((randomNumber[0] % numberSides) + 1);`

Comment: Yes, the mod operator solves the dice problem and, with a little more work, the 5-digit problem to the satisfaction of most.  However, if randomness is *very* important, there is something extra to consider.  If the RNGCSP returns a byte, it can be from 0 to 255 in value.  So you mod it 6 and add 1.  But doing this, of the 256 possible values of that byte, values yielding a 1, 2, 3, or 4 using Idle_Mind's formula will each come up 43 out of 256 times. 5 and 6 will each come up only 42 out of 256 times.  Therefore before taking the mod, you should throw out any byte value 252-255 and reroll it.

Comment: @Preston Guillot: If you're running an online casino, or similar, then your random numbers need to be 100% secure. If your dice rolls exhibit any bias then somebody, somewhere will notice and take you to the cleaners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. How do you generate 5 digit long numbers with RNGCSP?**

For the numbers, you can use a range. You'll have to think of the lower bound yourself though. Ranges for number are treated in [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6299708/589259).

So for a 5 digit number `min` would be `0` or `10000` and `max` would be `100000`, because `max` is *exclusive*.

**2. How do you generate numbers from 1 to 6 (excluding zeroes)?**

Basically the same way, you generate a range [1, 7) where 7 - the `max` value - is exclusive.

If you just want a dice result you can just do something like this (untested!):

```
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] singleByteBuf = new byte[1];
int max = Byte.MaxValue - Byte.MaxValue % 6;
while (true) {
    rng.GetBytes(singleByteBuf);
    int b = singleByteBuf[0];
    if (b < max) {
        return b % 6 + 1;
    }
 }
```

Basically the same idea, but is only requests 1 byte at a time from the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`, so it doesn't waste 3 additional bytes.