# Generate unique passwords

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am making a app to generate passwords, now i have write a unit test to test when you generate 2 passwords they are unique, but i got the problem they are not unique but just the same.

Unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void PasswordGeneratorShouldRenderUniqueNextPassword()
{
    // Create an instance, and generate two passwords
    var generator = new PasswordGenerator();
    var firstPassword = generator.Generate(8);
    var secondPassword = generator.Generate(8);

    // Verify that both passwords are unique
    Assert.AreNotEqual(firstPassword, secondPassword);
}
```

Something in here is wrong i guess:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
 {
     int x = random.Next(0, length);

     if (!password.Contains(chars.GetValue(x).ToString()))
         password += chars.GetValue(x);
     else
         i--;
 }
 if (length < password.Length) password = password.Substring(0, length);

 return password;
```

Random:

```
 Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

Comment: Please show how you initialize `Random`. You are almost certainly using the same seed each time...

Comment: I'm guessing the `for` loop belongs to `PasswordGenerator.Generate()` ?

Comment: you are probably using a constant seed when you instantiate `Random`.

Comment: Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

Comment: You need to instantiate a new Random once only in your application, and then generate new random numbers from that seed.

Answer (score 5):

If you generate two passwords very quickly they will be generated on the same tick.

---

If you just want to generate a random human readable password, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55447/659190). If you want to know why `Random` is not good for this purpose and how you might do something more appropriate read on.

---

<s>The quickest thing to do is use the default constructor of `Random()`, that will do the seeding for you.</s>

After checking [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx), the default constructor uses a time based seed, so you'd suffer the same issues with its use. Anyway, the `Random` class is too predictable to use for safe password generation.

If you are looking  for a little more strength you could do this,

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

static string GetPassword(int length = 13)
{
   var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
   var buffer = new byte[length * sizeof(char)];
   rng.GetNonZeroBytes(buffer);
   return new string(Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(buffer));
}
```

---

However, if you want humans to be able to read, remember and type your generated passwords you should be a little more limited in your range of possible characters.

---

**I've updated this part to give a detailed, modern, unbiased answer.**

If you want to limit output to a certain set of chars you can do something like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

/// <summary>
/// Get a random password.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="valid">A list of valid password chars.</param>
/// <param name="length">The length of the password.</returns>
/// <returns>A random password.</returns>
public static string GetPassword(IList<char> valid, int length = 13)
{
    return new string(GetRandomSelection(valid, length).ToArray());
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets a random selection from <paramref name="valid"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The item type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="valid">List of valid possibilities.</param>
/// <param name="length">The length of the result sequence.</param>
/// <returns>A random sequence</returns>
private static IEnumerable<T> GetRandomSelection<T>(
        IList<T> valid,
        int length)
{
    // The largest multiple of valid.Count less than ulong.MaxValue.
    // This upper limit prevents bias in the results.
    var max = ulong.MaxValue - (ulong.MaxValue % (ulong)valid.Count);

    // A finite sequence of random ulongs.
    var ulongs = RandomUInt64Sequence(max, length).Take(length);

    // A sequence of indecies.
    var indecies = ulongs.Select((u => (int)(u % (ulong)valid.Count)));

    return indecies.Select(i => valid[i]);
}

/// <summary>
/// An infinite sequence of random <see cref="ulong"/>s.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="max">
/// The maximum inclusive <see cref="ulong"/> to return.
/// </param>
/// <param name="poolSize">
/// The size, in <see cref="ulong"/>s, of the pool used to
/// optimize <see cref="RNGCryptoServiceProvider"/> calls.
/// </param>
/// <returns>A random <see cref="ulong"/> sequence.</returns>
private static IEnumerable<ulong RandomUInt64Sequence(
        ulong max = UInt64.MaxValue,
        int poolSize = 100)
{
    var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var pool = new byte[poolSize * sizeof(ulong)];

    while (true)
    {
        rng.GetBytes(pool);
        for (var i = 0; i < poolSize; i++)
        {
            var candidate = BitConvertor.ToUInt64(pool, i * sizeof(ulong));
            if (candidate > max)
            {
                continue;
            }

            yield return candidate;
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can use this code like this, first you need a set of valid `char`a that could be in your password,

```
var validChars = new[] { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
```

for ilustration i've included just 3 `char`s, in practice you'd want many more `char`s to be included. Then, to genrate a random password 8 `char`s long you make this call.

```
var randomPassword = GetPassword(validChars, 8);
```

In practice, you probably want your passwords to be at least 13 `char`s.

Comment: @user2139293, I've extended my answer

Comment: +1 for being the only answer to note that `Random` is not random enough for password generation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are Your problem is that you are using the default Random constrctor, which uses the current date/time as a seed. DateTime.Ticks has a resolution of 100 nanoseconds. This is quick, but not quick enough for your unit test, which is generating both passswords in less than 100 ns.

One solution is to use a static Random instance in your password generator.

```
public class PasswordGenerator
{
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public string Generate()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            int x = random.Next(0, length);

            if (!password.Contains(chars.GetValue(x).ToString()))
                password += chars.GetValue(x);
            else
                i--;
        }
        if (length < password.Length) password = password.Substring(0, length);

        return password;
    }
}
```

Comment: The resolution of `Ticks` is also much greater than the accuracy of it.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now.Ticks` is not very accurate, while it appears to represent a very small slice of time, it actually represents several milliseconds.

Since your password algorithm probably takes a tenth of a millisecond, this is causing `DateTime.Now.Ticks` to have the same value.

Two alternatives are to provide a way to give a seed (that would let you use a third random number generator to create seeds) or pass in a random object (that would ensure that the two are created sequentially off the same seed, creating different values).

Answer (score 0):

I would create the `Random` object within the `PasswordGenerator` constructor, to ensure that every time you call the `Generate` method, you will get a number that is (more or less) random.

```
public PassworGenerator()
{
    random = new Random(/* seed */);
}
```