# Temporary Password Generator for C# Project

Tags: c#, passwords

We are using the following methods to create temporary passwords, I am wondering if this is a good practice, since Random is not truly random. 
Beside the fact that we should generate it with another list of valid characters I highly doubt that this is random enough:

```
   public static string CreatePassword(int length)
            {
                const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
                StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
                Random rnd = new Random();
                while (0 < length--)
                {
                    res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
                }
                return res.ToString();
            }
```

Should we add some other randomness e.g. process Id or something similar?
Or maybe "new Random" just needs a some kind of salt?

The question I am asking here is more specific, since I am asking about specific problems with the given code I am providing. My question is not how to generate random temporary passwords, but how the code I am providing is problematic and why the answers and suggestions are better in these regards. Maybe I should have posted it in the "Code Reivew" Stack. But I personally do not see it as exact dupblicate of the other question.

Comment: Here is a little salt advice from Microsoft: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288534(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: I think you should move Random out of the method and use its only instance instead of creating it again and again

Comment: I think they talk about password encryption and not generation. Not sure.

Comment: According to this definition it uses the system clock seed when you provide nothing. So it should be OK to have it inside the method? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Matthias You need to use the same instance of `Random` if you generate numbers quickly like that. See this example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fMV8nM

Comment: OK. So actually it is the same as it was in C in the old days. Since the seed will always be the same (system clock does not change that face). It generates the same over and over again. This is probably a bug if you need to create multiple passwords at a team. We should initialise the Random instance probably even at application startup?

Comment: Cool Fiddle! It helped me to see immediately the problem.

Comment: I think you could phrase a good answer out of this?

Comment: Well, it depends. If you think you might be generating more than one password at a time, it could be a problem. You might create a `PasswordGenerator` class that has a static instance of `Random` to use. Otherwise, you might just use the built in `System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword()` that kyle suggested so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: System.Web is a bit outdated I think. When we want to be ready for vNext. But I did not says that in my initial question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating Random Passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991/generating-random-passwords)

Comment: @kyle: I think my question is different in terms of the code I am providing. Also if I look at the comments these are valuable for my situation. I think it is good enough to link the two questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator (CSPRNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator). e.g.

```
RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
rng.GetBytes(saltValue);
```

Using `Random` is seeded by current time of day. This means that an attacker could generate the same password as a user using this function if they know (or guess) the time of day that it was generated. A cryptographically secure random function does not have this flaw:

> CSPRNG requirements fall into two groups: first, that they pass
>   statistical randomness tests; and secondly, that they hold up well
>   under serious attack, even when part of their initial or running state
>   becomes available to an attacker

Answer (score 1):

For web application I think you can use [`System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(int length, int numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword.aspx).

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I would be interested also in if the approach we are using is reasonable or not. I will think about using what you provide here.