# Combine different Random Characters to one String

Tags: c#, random

I am programming an C# Application, which should generate a random Password. My thought was to use the "Random" to generate 10 different Chars and combine them into 1 String.

So I made this Method, which returns a random Char:

```
public static string RandomChar()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    var chars ="$%#@!*abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890?;:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ^&".ToCharArray();
    string indexValue = chars.GetValue(random.Next(chars.Length)).ToString();           
    return indexValue;
}
```

This Method works as intended so far.

Then I made the following Method to generate a single string with 10 random chars:

```
public static string RandomPwd()  
{
    string Pwd = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        Pwd= Pwd + RandomChar();
    }
    return Pwd;
}
```

And then I simply call the RandomPwd() Method from on OnClick event. (I dont think this onClick Event is nessesary to show since the only thing it does there, is calling RandomPwd().)

The weird part is, that if I start the Application with an Breakpoint on

```
string a = RandomPwd();
```

"a" will always be a 10 Characters long string of SAME Charakters, like "UUUUUUUUUU".

But If i set the Breakpoint on the following:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        Pwd= Pwd + RandomChar();
    }
    return Pwd;
```

Then I can see, that Pwd is getting filled with 10 DIFFERENT Characters. And if I continue stepping through, I also notice, that

```
string a = RandomwPwd();
```

is now 10 Characters long of different Chars.

So it looks like the application works fine, as long as i step through manually, but if I dont, then it wont take different Randoms.

I´ve searched for that Problem on Google and on here, but I couldnt find anything which solves my Problem.

Maybe someone else has experienced that before and would share his Solution to this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do NOT create a `Random` inside a method that you call very quickly. Its seed is taken from the system clock, which has a granularity of ~50ms.

Comment: Oh wow, I didnt knew that! Thanks for the fast response and the help.

Comment: @MatthewWatson You can get away with it in .NET Core. I don't know the details yet, but when I was creating a snippet for question of this sort to demonstrate the issue in .NET Core I was getting different numbers.

Comment: @tymtam Ooh, so they have! That's nice. [Source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Random.cs,124)

Comment: Here is my gist to generate random string out of some domain. Which is both thread safe and will not be generated out of same seed - https://gist.github.com/eocron/fab4fe6a113fbc1ef15213b9e9e2f8e4.

Comment: Good to see that they've fixed this issue in .Net Core - especially given the number of times people make that mistake!

Comment: Btw to generate random password use built in solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54991/generating-random-passwords

Answer (score -2):

You need to take `Random random = new Random();` from inside the method.

`new Random().Next(...)` called in a tight loop will often produce the same number.

---

```
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++)
{
     Random random = new Random();
     Console.WriteLine(random.Next(0,100));
}
```

produced

```
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
```

Comment: This is completely wrong.

Comment: @eocron Hey, thanks for feedback, which part is wrong?

Comment: This explains the problem, but is not an answer.

Comment: Your answer is obscure, it does not give insight to why this happening, what could be done and just contains invalid example (though it is valid to pinpoint problem). Also, question is already marked as duplicate and link have a good explanation so it is meaningless to repeat.

Comment: @eocron Ok, so you think it could be improved, or that is was not necessary. That different to "wrong" :)