# how to generate random password list in c# and add in listbox

Tags: c#

I want to make an password list generator app I not found anything about generate 1000 password at a time most youtube videos generating 1 password

sample code

```
int minLength = 15;
int maxLength = 15;

string charavailalbe = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

StringBuilder password = new StringBuilder();
Random random = new Random();
int passwordLength = random.Next(minLength, maxLength + 1);

while (passwordLength-- > 0)
{  
    password.Append(charavailalbe[random.Next(charavailalbe.Length)]);
}
listBox1.Items.Add(password.ToString());
```

Comment: You need [a loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements). Take care to define `random` *outside* the loop (to avoid using the same seed for multiple passwords), and, while you're at it, remove `Random` and [use a secure cryptographic random number generator instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54991/87698).

Comment: And yes, it always scares me a bit to see security-critical code developed by people who still struggle to grasp the very basics of the programming language they use (no offense meant)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to generate 1000 passwords, put your code inside a for-loop wich executes 1000 times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    // generate a password and add the resulting password to your listBox1
}
```

You probably should put your password generation code inside a method, so you only need to call the method inside the for loop.